# VMWare Clarity - master branch - `npm run angular:dev:start` fails with ERROR: Task not found: "'core:build:ts"

Tags: vmware-clarity

Unable to run dev mode of Clarity after checking out master.

Following error is reported.

```
λ npm run angular:dev:start

> @clr/clarity@3.0.0-next.8 angular:dev:start C:\Users\shrees3\Documents\clarity
> npm run core:build:src && ng serve dev


> @clr/clarity@3.0.0-next.8 core:build:src C:\Users\shrees3\Documents\clarity
> npm-run-all core:build:sass:components 'core:build:ts -- --force'

ERROR: Task not found: "'core:build:ts"
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @clr/clarity@3.0.0-next.8 core:build:src: `npm-run-all core:build:sass:components 'core:build:ts -- --force'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @clr/clarity@3.0.0-next.8 core:build:src script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shrees3\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-20T14_17_10_235Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @clr/clarity@3.0.0-next.8 angular:dev:start: `npm run core:build:src && ng serve dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @clr/clarity@3.0.0-next.8 angular:dev:start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shrees3\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-20T14_17_10_370Z-debug.log
```

**Steps tried:**

1. Clone Clarity and checkout `master` branch.
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `npm run angular:dev:start`

**Platform**

1. Windows Laptpop
2. Using https://cmder.net/ Command Window which supports typical linux utilities.
3. Angular: 9.0.2
4. Node: 10.16.0
5. Clarity: "3.0.0-next.8"

Answer (score 0):

The angular app depends on the core components. 
Can you try running

```
npm run core:build
```

and then rerun

```
npm run angular:dev:start
```

Comment: Same error on `npm run core:build`.  Jeremy from your team thinks its a windows-specific issue https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/4301#issuecomment-589252073

Comment: I tried running the command directly `node_modules\.bin\npm-run-all.cmd core:build:sass -p core:build:package 'core:build:ts -- --force' core:build:api core:build:clean`  - it too reports same error.

Comment: I used double quotes for "core:build.ts" instead of single quotes - `node_modules\.bin\npm-run-all.cmd core:build:sass -p core:build:package "core:build:ts -- --force" core:build:api core:build:clean`  -- it went bit further but errored out with different message `Fatal error:  Didn't find any files to analyze.
Error: Didn't find any files to analyze. .....Cannot copy `'**/package.json'`: the file doesn't exist`

Comment: While this is a problem building on a PC, the best solution is to use the Ubuntu shell on Windows 10. The alternative is to help reconfigure the scripts to work with Windows, but changing quotes has potential side effects that might cause it to break the build in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Response from Clarity Team on [Github issue](https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/4301):

> This is a Windows specific issue with the handling of single quotes '. We don't actively develop on Windows so don't always catch these things. The quotes probably need to be escaped for Windows, unless you opt to use the Ubuntu shell.